# Proof of the expected value of the Frechet distribution

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, expected-value

Consider a Frechet distribution with the following cumulative distribution function:

$$Pr(X \leq x) = e^{-x^{-\alpha}} ~ \quad\mbox{if}\quad~ x>0$$

The expected value is $E(X) = \Gamma(1 - \frac{1}{\alpha})$ with the gamma function: $\Gamma(a) = \int_0^{\infty} x^{a-1}e^{-x} dx$.

I am struggling to prove the above expected value.

$$E(X) = \int_0^{\infty} x \alpha x^{-\alpha -1} e^{-x^{-\alpha}} dx$$

Using a change of variable $y=x^{-\alpha}$ so $dy = - \alpha x^{-\alpha-1} dx$ and $x = y^{\frac{-1}{\alpha}}$.

Then, I would be tempted to write $E(X) = \int_0^{\infty} \textbf{-} y^{\frac{-1}{\alpha}} e^{-y} dy$ instead of $E(X) = \int_0^{\infty} y^{\frac{-1}{\alpha}} e^{-y} dy$, because $dy = \textbf{-}$ something.

Should be trivial but why did the sign minus disappear?

Comment: When you do the transformation, what happens to your limits?

Comment: Thanks @Glen_b but what do you mean by "what happens to your limits" in this specific case?

Comment: When you do a change of variable with a definite integral, *what happens to the limits on the integral*?

Comment: @Glen_b Do you want to me to understand that I can simply write: $-\int_0^\infty y^{\frac{-1}{\alpha}} e^{-y} dy = \int_{-\infty}^0 y^{\frac{-1}{\alpha}} e^{-y} dy = \int_0^\infty y^{\frac{-1}{\alpha}} e^{-y} dy$ ?

Comment: @emeryville $y=\frac{1}{x^a}$. As $x \longrightarrow 0$, $y \longrightarrow \infty$ and as $x \longrightarrow \infty$, $y \longrightarrow ...$

Comment: @rightskewed I understand that as $x \longrightarrow \infty, y \longrightarrow 0$ but I am unable to figure out how this hint is related to my problem. Sorry about that.

Comment: @emeryville Your first and second step in your comment there is wrong, and your original error is actually at the previous step to what you started with (both that and your second error in the comment come from what looks like the same misunderstanding). $\int_a^b f(x) dx \neq \int_b^a f(x) dx$. You need to back up one step and *pay attention to the limits* as you pass from an integral in $x$ to an integral in $y$, and keep in mind that you can't just flip the limits on your integral willy-nilly.

Comment: @Glen_b thanks for this comment. I appreciate your help and the time you devoted to this question. Yes, I didn't pay attention to the limits. Now, it's obvious that I missed that as $x \in (0, \infty)$, $y \in (\infty, 0)$, and then the limits of the integral change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$E(X) = \int_0^{\infty} x \alpha x^{-\alpha -1} e^{-x^{-\alpha}} dx$$

Let $y=x^{-\alpha}$ so $dy = - \alpha x^{-\alpha-1} dx$ and $x = y^{\frac{-1}{\alpha}}$. For $x \in (0, \infty)$, $y \in (\infty, 0)$

Thus,

$$
\begin{align*}
E(X) &= \int_0^{\infty} x e^{-x^{-\alpha}} (\alpha x^{-\alpha -1} dx)\\
&= \int_\infty^{0} y^{\frac{-1}{\alpha}} e^{-y} (-dy)\\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} y^{\frac{-1}{\alpha}} e^{-y} dy\ \text{by interchanging limits}\\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} y^{\big(1-\frac{1}{\alpha}\big)-1} e^{-y} dy\\
&= \Gamma(1-\frac{1}{\alpha})
\end{align*}
$$